# multiple if's for calculated field in tableau

Tags: if-statement, tableau-api

please pardon the absolutely newbie question but i'm very new to tableau.
what I'd like to do is create a message based on which filter flags are active. so, in psuedo code, i'd do something like this:

```
message = ''
if filter1 == 1:
  message += 'filter 1 is active'
if filter2 == 1:
  message += ' filter 2 is active'
return message
```

problem is, I'm not even sure how to do multiple if statements - i keep getting a syntax error. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: this is tableau: http://www.tableausoftware.com/tableau-software-1A?kw=tableau&adused=6167802135&gclid=CPe_1dC98acCFYS8KgodXV2caA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what I ended up doing is creating a calculated field for each if statement. I then created yet another calculated field that concatenates all of the output from each of the first set of calculated fields I created. Seems like a bit of a hack so If anyone knows of a more elegant way of doing this (making a calculated field of a series of calulated fields seems awfully kludgy) I'd be glad to pass on the points for answering.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of how I accomplished something similar:

```
IF [ZAVUFA1_FED_COLL_CHOICE_1] = 'xxxxx' THEN 1
ELSEIF [ZAVUFA1_FED_COLL_CHOICE_2] = 'xxxxx' THEN 2
ELSEIF [ZAVUFA1_FED_COLL_CHOICE_3] = 'xxxxx' THEN 3
ELSEIF [ZAVUFA1_FED_COLL_CHOICE_4] = 'xxxxx' THEN 4
ELSEIF [ZAVUFA1_FED_COLL_CHOICE_5] = 'xxxxxx' THEN 5
ELSEIF [ZAVUFA1_FED_COLL_CHOICE_6] = 'xxxxx' THEN 6
ELSEIF [ZAVUFA1_FED_COLL_CHOICE_7] = 'xxxxxx' THEN 7
ELSEIF [ZAVUFA1_FED_COLL_CHOICE_8] = 'xxxxxx' THEN 8
ELSEIF [ZAVUFA1_FED_COLL_CHOICE_9] = 'xxxxx' THEN 9
ELSEIF [ZAVUFA1_FED_COLL_CHOICE_10] = 'xxxxxx' THEN 10
ELSEIF ISNULL([ZAVUFA1_FED_COLL_CHOICE_1]) THEN 99
END
```

As much as I love stackoverflow, Tableau also has a great user forum on their site.

Comment: looks like a new tag needs to be added, that is "Tableau".

Comment: not ELSEIF.just IF. What i've had to do is create multiple calculated fields for each if statement and then another calculated field concatenating all of them.

Comment: @Ramy.  I guess I don't understand what the difference is between referencing a field or another calculated expression inside of an expression.  Furthermore, if you look at my code, I am referencing different objects (calculations) as you do. in your example.  Simply, I guess I don't understand what you are looking to do, as my example matches your toy example

Comment: @Btibert3, the difference is that I'd like to accumulate the string and add to it for every instance that is equal to 1. So if filters 1 and 2 are both set to 1, then i'd like the text to be "filter 1 filter 2". if only filter 1 is set to 1 then I'd like the return value to be set to 'filter 1'. does that make sense?

Comment: with elseIF, it'll stop at the first one that evaluates to true and skip all the rest.

Comment: @Ramy that makes more sense.....I just learned you can concatenate in Tableau by using '+' on strings.  I am stumped

Answer (score 1):

You would create a calculated field called message with this code:

```
IF filter1 = 1 THEN 'filter 1 is active' END
+ IF filter2 = 1 THEN ' filter 2 is active' END
```